# Convert json to array and compare the difference

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I am trying to take the returned results from these two json and compare the differences to only show unique values. I have tried many other methods yet nothing seems to works. This code gives me Argument #1 is not an array...any help what i'm missing here?

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("http://ebird.org/ws1.1/data/obs/region/recent?rtype=subnational1&r=US-AZ&back=7&fmt=json");
$json2 = file_get_contents("http://ebird.org/ws1.1/data/obs/region/recent?rtype=subnational1&r=US-NV&back=7&fmt=json");

$array1 = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$array2 = json_decode($json2, TRUE);

$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

echo $result ;

?>
```

now the result is 'Array' yet I know that there are differences.... is there some way to compare just one field in the returned json data...in this instance com-name?

Comment: Uhm. You're talking json, but your variable names are $xml and $xml2 ?

Comment: sorry about that, was trying it with xml first..i've updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are strings (urls) not JSON.
You are trying to json_decode a url!

Also if I visit the url, I get XML ... Not JSON.

Comment: I saw that I updated the url so now it returns json- &fmt instead of &format.

Comment: +1 for catching they aren't actually grabbing that data. I overlooked that.

Comment: @JonathanCoffey Nope. Still give XML... And even then. You need to GET the contents of the URL and try to json_decode that, in stead json_decoding the URL itsself. Try `$xml = file_get_contents("http://blahblahblah");` and `$xml2 = file_get_contents("http://blahblahblah");` once you figured out the correct urls

Comment: So safe to say first i need to convert url to json object, decode then compare?

Comment: @JonathanCoffey , no . You first have to get the contents in the url. There is a difference between a url and the content you can see once you enter this specific url. For example : $url = "www.bbc.com";
Converting $url to json will only convert the string "www.bbc.com". If you want to actually convert the articles shown in bbc.com , you first have to get them using file_get_contents().

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get the data from those URLs.
2. You need to pass `true` as the 2nd parameter to [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get the results as an array:

.

```
$xml  = file_get_contents('http://ebird.org/ws1.1/data/obs/region/recent?rtype=subnational1&r=US-AZ&back=7&format=json');
$xml2 = file_get_contents('http://ebird.org/ws1.1/data/obs/region/recent?rtype=subnational1&r=US-NV&back=7&format=json');

$array1 = json_decode($xml, true);
$array2 = json_decode($xml2, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is actually trying to decode the **URL ADDRESSES** to JSON format, and not the content that is found in those specific url addresses.
In order to JSON decode the contnent and not the URL itself, you might use the following code:

```
$content = file_get_contents($xml); //get the content that is found in the url that $xml holds
$json = json_decode($content);  //now json decode the content , and not the url itself
```

I hope it helped you to understand what you've done wrong. Using the file_get_contents() and the json_decode() functions is the easy part,  first you have to plan what your code should actually do.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As the above posters said, you will need to actually retrieve the file. Just calling json_decode will just try to decode a JSON string, which is not at all what you are trying to achieve.